# Cannot see self created certificate in certmanager?

Tags: windows, windows-7, ssl-certificate

I followed the steps in my answer to create a certificate. I will use this cert on my own computer. The command succeeded, but I see no personal certificate in cert manager (certmgr.msc). Answer - [How do I create client certificates for local testing of two-way authentication over SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031200/how-do-i-create-client-certificates-for-local-testing-of-two-way-authentication)

Steps:

1. Launch Vs2010 Command Prompt: Start ► All Programs ► Visual Studio 2010 ► Visual Studio Tools ► Visual Studio Command Prompt (right click and Run as Administrator)
2. Create a self-signed (-r), private key exportable (-pe), saving to personal folder (-ss my) under local machine (Local Computer, sr localmachine), named (-n) "YangsoftCA",common name (-in) "Yangsoft.com" with private key file (-sv) as "YangsoftCA.pvk" and public key file "YangsoftCA.cer"

Command:

```
C:\Windows\system32>makecert -r -pe -ss my -sr LocalMachine -n "CN=YangsoftCA" -sv "YangsoftCA.pvk" YangsoftCA.cer
```

Above succeeded

Password was prompted to secure the private key file

This is what my cert manager looks like. There is nothing under personal certificates. 
I was hoping that yangsoft would appear there.

[image]

How do I find out what happened and how do I see my cert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `mmc.exe`. Follow the steps:

- MMC > File > Add/remove snap-in > Certificates > You get three options:

  1. My user account
  2. Service account
  3. Computer account

I don't know what it means, so I took My user account. It seems to be my lucky card in other problems.

Finish.

Then you will need to activate IIS server manager on your system:

- control panel > programs and features > turn windows features on or off > IIS, the full name > ok

Once done, it can be seen in `mmc.exe`. In IIS server, under IIS list, click server certificates > create self signed certificate. Enter some stuff and you should be done.

Answer (score 4):

make sure you are checking under user certificate, not in computer certificate:
[image: make sure you are checking under user certificate, not in computer certificate]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you -- I used to type certmgr to launch the tool, but today it was launching computer not user.  Picked from lower down in list on user certs and it's working.  Thanks!